# Gnuplot wrapper for parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, gnuplot

I need to process a big number of data file with gnuplot in order to produce images which are collected in a movie. As the procedure is time consuming I would like to produce the frames in parallel and a small message should be printed from time to time to inform the user of the progress.

I tried the makefile approach:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard ./*.in)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.in=.out)

all: $(OBJECTS)

%.out: %.in
  ./worker.sh $< $@
```

where worker.sh is:

```
gnuplot << EOF
set some_gnuplot_options
set output "$2"
plot "$1" 
EOF
```

But:

1. I cannot print the progress messages,
2. I would prefer a single file solution (I have not succeeded in having the content of `worker.sh` directly in the makefile),
3. This solution introduces pretty much overhead with respect to a single gnuplot script wich contains all the instructions.

Probably the definitive solution would be to have a nice c++ interface to gnuplot, but I don't know very well the existing ones and I'm not sure how to do the job. Any other idea? Please avoid to imply new or not so common programs like GNU parallel as I cannot have them on some machines I use.

Comment: If your reason for not having GNU Parallel on you machine is not covered by http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html could you be kind to elaborate on the reason?

Comment: Because I am not allowed to install software AND I would like to minimize the number of scripts to be carried around especially 3th part AND I don't think that it could bring performance improvements with respect to makefile (still has to load gnuplot each time) AND finally I don't know it very well.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it sounds as if you are allowed to use your own scripts. GNU Parallel can be used as a script and does not need to be installed, and you can then create a file `parallel_plotter`:

```
#!/home/tange/bin/parallel --shebang-wrap -v A={} /usr/bin/gnuplot

name=system("echo $A")
set term png
set output name.".png"
plot sin(x*name)/x
```

Substitute /home/tange/bin/parallel with the full path to where you put the script parallel.

Then:

```
chmod 755 parallel_plotter
./parallel_plotter 1 2 3 4 5
```

This will print a line for each completed run.

---

To avoid the full path to /home/tange/bin/parallel I can come up with this solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

name=system("echo $A")
set term png
set output name.".png"
plot sin(x*name)/x
```

Then:

```
chmod 755 parallel_plotter
parallel -v A={} ./parallel_plotter ::: 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

You are worried that spawning gnuplot will give a lot of overhead. I tested the above with:

```
./parallel_plotter {1..1000}
```

That took 10 secs. So the overhead of starting gnuplot on my system is less than 100 ms per job.

Comment: Ok, thank this solution. I am reluctant to include the full path to the script as in principle I will have to distribute it with the rest of the code and who knows in which folder it will end up?

Comment: I understand your reluctance, and I wish I had a way to do the /home/tange/bin/parallel without giving full path. Unfortunately the trick to use 'env' does not work in this case (#!/usr/bin/env parallel). So if you do find a way to avoid the full path to parallel in the #!-line, I will be very happy to learn about it.